# JDialog - How can I set a fixed width and variable height?

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JDialog` object that, quite simply, **MUST be 200 pixels wide**, regardless of its contents.

I need to be able to have the **height adjusted dynamically**, to always ensure that all the content is shown. How do I go about it?

- I've tried overriding `JDialog.getPreferredSize()` method, but I can't figure out what to add for the height value.
- I've tried checking if the `main` JPanel `isValid()` and `isShowing()`, however, both return true as long as a part of the Panel is actually visible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Preferred sizes are only for layout managers, they cannot restrict window sizes.

The window peer has a method for enforcing minimum size, so that works very well, but there is nothing for maximum size other than listening for resizes and resetting to desired size:

```
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            Dimension size = getSize();
            size.width = 200;
            setSize(size);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the height dynamically to ensure that all the content is visible? Thanks!

Comment: Window.pack() does that provided all your preferred sizes are correct.

Comment: `Window.pack()` asks for the window's `getPreferredSize()` (and all its sub-components) and sets it to that. However, if my preferred size is (e.g.) `450 x 32`, and assuming I set the width to be fixed at 200, the preferred HEIGHT is still 32. Thus, some of the content is clipped

Comment: You need to adjust your preferred sizes so that they have a width of 200 for the window. This is quite easy with a modern layout manager such as MigLayout without even overriding getPreferredSize.

Answer (score 0):

When overriding `getPreferredSize()`, you can ask the superclass about the height:

```
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    Dimension superPref = super.getPreferredSize();
    return new Dimension(200, superPref.getHeight());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a JDialog you could override the `getPreferredSize` method like this:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
}
```

Or specifying explicitly the dimension:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(width, height);
}
```